# Possible implementation of game screen concept for an android game

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to develop an android app, but I'm still not that great at using xml or the eclipse wysiwyg editor to make scalable and robust interfaces!

Below is a quick concept I drew up on word of what my main game screen will consist of:

[image]

I'm currently thinking a vertical linear frame first, with a frame that doesn't change for my important stats etc., then a frame in the middle which is switched by the buttons, but I'm stuck on how to implement this.

For the centre button screen, the map screen, I am hoping to add an image of a map which can be moved around, and somehow attach invisible button objects to points in this picture, maybe with an array of squares or something?

I understand this is a pretty open question and might be difficult to answer, but if you think you can help in anyway please do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a log of possibilities, but you can use a `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and include your stats in top. For the changing screens with buttons you can use a `FragmentTabHost` and create different `Fragment` for each of your views. 
Check [this example](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) with a implementation.

Regarding the map, I think the easiest option is to use [Google Maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/). Here is a [example to use the maps v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) and a example of [how to add markers to the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).

Comment: Regarding the example, if I'm starting a project from scratch do you think it's worth just having my main GUI class extend TabActivity to avoid having to create another class?

Comment: `TabActivity` is deprecated since **API 13**. You should use `Fragments` instead of that. Check more information in the [TabActivity Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html "TabActivity Android documentation")